# Exceptions and File I/O

Tags: java, exception, file-io, null, average

Hello people I need help, when I run my code it outputs this :

```
Average = 49.91791791791792

null

empty.txt is empty


    Error: notThere.txt (No such file or directory)

Average = 0.0
```

but my goal is to have it output this:

```
Average = 49.91791791791792

squeeze.txt does not have numeric data

empty.txt is empty

Error: notThere.txt (No such file or directory)

Average = 0.0
```

I have problems understanding this step for the assignment: 
Throw the following exceptions in the scanDataAndCalculateAverage method
File is empty.
File has non-numeric data. You can assume that the data file does not have non-numeric and numeric data mixed in. This is done by checking if something was read in but the count is 0.

Can you guys help me? Here is the code:http://pastebin.com/33WCBxEf

```
public class Average {
        long total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String asd = "";
        public Average(String a){
                asd = a;}
        public double scanDataAndCalculateAverage(){
            try {           
                FileReader f = new FileReader(asd);
                Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
                while (in.hasNext()){
                    total += in.nextInt();
                    count++;
                }
                if(count==0 && in.hasNext() == true){
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(asd + " does not have numeric data");
                }
                if(count == 0 && total == 0){
                        throw new ArithmeticException(asd + " is empty");
                 } 
                return (double)total/count;
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                return 0;
            }
       }
 }
```

Comment: its better if you share code in the question rather than an external link.

Comment: Format your code and question nicely, post it here (there is not that much) and reconsider *exactly* what your question is. Maybe you can simply check if the reuslt is null and if so, print "filename does not have numeric data".

Comment: in.hasNext will not be true after the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the while loop:

```
while (in.hasNext()){
   total += in.nextInt();
   count++;
}
```

This loop exits only when hasNext returns false, which meanse count==0 && in.hasNext will never be true. Probably, you want the loop to only process ints.

This might work better:

```
while (in.hasNextInt()){
   total += in.nextInt();
   count++;
}
```

The loop will end when there is no int - however hasNext will still be true, since there may be letters, etc in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
            while (in.hasNextInt()){
                total += in.nextInt();
                count++;
            }
            if(count==0 && in.hasNextInt() == false){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(asd + " does not have numeric data");
            }
```

Yeah thats most probably it. Try it!